# Java calculator, terminates

Tags: java

My calculator terminates whenever divided by 0 or a non integer is used. I can't get my while loop to work.

Can anyone help, and explain how I fix this problem?

edit:

it still terminates though.

```
package b;

import java.util.*;


public class Calculator3{


    static boolean _state = true;
    public static void main (String[] args){

        System.out.println("Usage: operand1 operator operand2");
        System.out.println("Operands are integers");
        System.out.println("Operators: + - * /");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{


        int result = 0;
        int operand1 = 0;
        int operand2 = 0;
        String operator = " ";
        char op = ' ';

        try{
        operand1 = in.nextInt();
        operator = in.next();
        op = operator.charAt(0);
        operand2 = in.nextInt();}

        catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("One or both of the operands are non-integers. Please check your operands");
            break;}





            try{
                switch (op){
                    case '+': result = operand1 + operand2;
                    break;
                    case '-': result = operand1 - operand2;
                    break;
                    case '*': result = operand1 * operand2;
                    break;
                    case '/': result = operand1 / operand2;
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("Unknown Operator");
                    break;}

            }

            catch(RuntimeException e){
                System.out.println("Operand2 cannot be 0");
                System.exit(0);}


            finally{
                System.out.println("Answer: " + operand1 + ' ' + op + ' ' + operand2 + " = " + result);}
        }
            while (_state = true);}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
} while (_state = true);
```

should be

```
} while (_state == true);
```

or better

```
} while (_state);
```

You need to avoid the following conditions to avoid exiting form the loop early:

- Inputting values & operators in incorrect order
- Using an expression that will cause an `ArithmeticException` such as `3/0`.

Comment: it still terminates though.

Comment: @user2540484 - It's going to always exit if you divide by zero.  You invoke `System.exit()` in your catch block.

Comment: Also another scenario if you don't inputting the values in the correct order - you will break out of the loop (from the exception block)

Comment: and instead of _state should be state and instead of state should be only true, it's not variable you don't change the value never..

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to divide by zero, an Exception will be thrown.

Your catch block invokes `System.exit()`.

This is why your code "*terminates*" when you divide by zero.

You should validate your input (make sure it's a real number) before using it for arithmetic.

I would do something like this:

```
do {
    try {
        char op = operator.charAt(0);
        int operand1 = in.nextInt();
        int operand2 = in.nextInt();
        if (operand2 == 0 && op == '/') {
            System.out.println("Cannot divide by zero");
            continue;    
        }
        .
        .
        .
        switch (op) {
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        continue; 
    }
} while (_state);
```

That's just one of many possible approaches.

Look at your try/catch logic and consider what should happen when different Exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

An [ArithmeticException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) is a `RuntimeException`.  The catch block triggers, and `System.exit(0)` is executed.  Think about how you want to handle errors.  Exiting probably isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
case '/':
    if (operand2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Operand2 cannot be 0");
        continue;
    } else {
        result = operand1 / operand2;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is exiting in 2 conditions .
First is 
`catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("One or both of the operands are non-integers. Please check your operands");
            break;}`

Remove this break if you still want to continue in case of non-integers i.e. double,float etc.

Second is

```
` catch(RuntimeException e){
            System.out.println("Operand2 cannot be 0");
            System.exit(0);}`
```

System.exit(0) is causing this while loop to break , if you want to continue, remove the System.exit(0);